# Need to route to different php files and call separate functions using .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phpmyadmin

Need to route the api calls to two different PHP files and call different functions inside those php files.

URL:
1) 
http://localhost/dual/LOGIN

this should call the login.php and inside that the function log_in() should be called

2) http://localhost/dual/REGISTER

this should call the register.php and inside that the function register_in() should be called

How to write the .htaccess file to allow such url rewriting

    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^LOGIN/$ login.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^REGISTER$ register.php?request=$1[QSA,NC,L]
```

Dont have idea regarding this .htaccess file..Need some help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/dual/` a real directory? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: dual is a real directory and .htaccess is present inside the dual folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **dual is a real directory and .htaccess is present inside the dual folder** then this simple .htaccess should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dual/

RewriteRule ^(login|register)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks and one more question ...if the php file name and the function name is different then..example.. http://localhost/dual/LOGIN

this should call the login.php and inside that the function log_in() should be called

Comment: In that case those URLs need to be handled individually eg. `RewriteRule ^something/?$ myfile.php [L,NC]`

Comment: Your suggestion was quite useful..I was able to hit the function.But the values which was sent from the android side , i was not able to receive it in the PHP/server side. DOes it anything to do with the .htaccess file or my rest file is not able to receive the values.If you want I can share the rest file as well. I am in real need of it.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dual_referral/
RewriteRule ^(LOGIN_DOC)$ login_doctor.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(REG_DOC_STUB)$ registration_doctor.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]...my .htaccess file

Comment: One point to be mentioned that when I am hitting from the rest client of chrome with the values, the values are getting passed and I am receiving the proper response also,but when the values are being passed from the android side the values getting passed are null

Comment: You can see the files in one more of post of mine in stackoverflow. URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422075/rest-php-receiving-values-from-android-side