# Rest PHP receiving values from android side

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, resteasy

REST File:Rest.inc.php

```
<?php

class REST {

    public $_allow = array();
    public $_content_type = "application/json";
    public $_request = array();

    private $_method = "";      
    private $_code = 200;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->inputs();
    }

    public function get_referer(){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }

    public function response($data,$status){
        $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
        $this->set_headers();
        echo $data;
        exit;
    }

    private function get_status_message(){
        $status = array(
                    100 => 'Continue',  
                    101 => 'Switching Protocols',  
                    200 => 'OK',
                    201 => 'Created',  
                    202 => 'Accepted',  
                    203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',  
                    204 => 'No Content',  
                    205 => 'Reset Content',  
                    206 => 'Partial Content',  
                    300 => 'Multiple Choices',  
                    301 => 'Moved Permanently',  
                    302 => 'Found',  
                    303 => 'See Other',  
                    304 => 'Not Modified',  
                    305 => 'Use Proxy',  
                    306 => '(Unused)',  
                    307 => 'Temporary Redirect',  
                    400 => 'Bad Request',  
                    401 => 'Unauthorized',  
                    402 => 'Payment Required',  
                    403 => 'Forbidden',  
                    404 => 'Not Found',  
                    405 => 'Method Not Allowed',  
                    406 => 'Not Acceptable',  
                    407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',  
                    408 => 'Request Timeout',  
                    409 => 'Conflict',  
                    410 => 'Gone',  
                    411 => 'Length Required',  
                    412 => 'Precondition Failed',  
                    413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',  
                    414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',  
                    415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',  
                    416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',  
                    417 => 'Expectation Failed',  
                    500 => 'Internal Server Error',  
                    501 => 'Not Implemented',  
                    502 => 'Bad Gateway',  
                    503 => 'Service Unavailable',  
                    504 => 'Gateway Timeout',  
                    505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported');
        return ($status[$this->_code])?$status[$this->_code]:$status[500];
    }

    public function get_request_method(){
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","get_request_method RESTS=>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","values of POST RESTS =>".$_POST);
        print_r($_POST);
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    private function inputs(){
        switch($this->get_request_method()){
            case "POST":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_POST);
                break;
            case "GET":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_GET);
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_DELETE);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$this->_request);
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($this->_request);
                break;
            default:
                $this->response('',406);
                break;
        }
    }       

    private function cleanInputs($data){
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","values of data =>".$data);
        $clean_input = array();
        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $k => $v){
                $clean_input[$k] = $this->cleanInputs($v);
            }
        }else{
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                $data = trim(stripslashes($data));
            }
            $data = strip_tags($data);
            $clean_input = trim($data);
        }

        $this->logger->write("INFO :","values of cleaninput =>".$clean_input);
        return $clean_input;
    }       

    private function set_headers(){
        header("HTTP/1.1".$this->_code." ".$this->get_status_message());
        header("Content-Type:".$this->_content_type);
    }

}   
?>
```

This is my REST file and one more class file is:

```
<?php

require_once("Rest.inc.php");

class TEST_REST extends REST {

    public $data = "";

    const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "";
    const DB = "doc_schema";

    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();              // Init parent contructor
        $this->dbConnect();                 // Initiate Database connection
        include_once("logger.php");
        $this->logger = new Logger();
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","PHP Scritp Name =>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","Type of Request =>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    }

    /*
     *  Database connection 
    */
    private function dbConnect(){
        $this->db = mysql_connect(self::DB_SERVER,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);
        if($this->db)
            mysql_select_db(self::DB,$this->db);
    }

    /*
     * Public method for access api.
     * This method dynmically call the method based on the query string
     *
     */
    public function processApi(){
        $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['request'])));
        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
            $this->$func();
        else
            $this->response('',404);                // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
    }


    private function TEST_VAL(){
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","Calling Update Location for Driver");
        // Cross validation if the request method is POST else it will return "Not Acceptable" status

        $val=$this->_request['val'];
        $val1=$_POST['val'];

        $this->logger->write("INFO :","login with val ----->".$val);
        $this->logger->write("INFO :","login with val1 ----->".$val1);

        if($val !="")
         {
            $success = array('status' => "Success", "val" => $val);
            $this->response($this->json($success),200);
         }
        else
         {
          $error = array('status' => "error");
          $this->response($this->json($error), 400);
         }

        }


    /*
     *  Encode array into JSON
    */
    private function json($data){
        if(is_array($data)){
            return json_encode($data);
        }
    }
}

// Initiiate Library

$api = new TEST_REST;
$api->processApi();
?>
```

FIle: .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /REST/
RewriteRule ^(TEST_VAL)$ test_Rest.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

URL when I am hitting from rest client chrome:

```
http://localhost/REST/TEST_VAL
```

and setting key params : val=>25

I'm getting response, but when hitting from android side, it's hitting the function but the value is null.

Comment: give me 5 mins..i will give it a try and let you know

Comment: print_r($_POST) printed 1 in my logfile inside the TEST_VAL  function

Comment: Anubhava, is the question clear or should I make it more easy in understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78625/discussion-between-rajeshwar-and-anubhava).